# How to print a PHP page without browser generated page numbers, URL, etc.?

Tags: php, css, printing, stylesheet

I have a PHP page that I need to print. I managed to remove unwanted elements from printing with a  print stylesheet (print.css) below. However it does not remove browser generated header, page numbers, URL and date. I am using bootstrap framework. bootstrap.min.css does not have any '@media print' sort of thing. Need some better CSS ideas to achieve this. Thank you.

```
    /* Remove unwanted elements */
    /* Assign class="noprint" in the HTML. Header and navigation (<div id="header"> and <div id="nav">) */

    #header, #nav, .noprint
    {
    display: none;
    }

   /* Ensure the content spans the full width */
   #container, #container2, #content
    {
    width: 100%; margin: 0; float: none;
    }

    /* Change text colour to black (useful for light text on a dark background) */
    .lighttext
    {
    color: #000 
    }

    /* Remove links */
    a:link, a:visited, .navbar-link
    {
    display: none;
    }
```

Comment: You can't control this with CSS. It is a browser/printer setting.

Answer (score 1):

In a browser like chrome, when you try to print the page (Ctrl+P) it will open a dialog box.
In this box you have to select "More definitions" or something similar and then, uncheck the option of headers. 
Other browsers, must have a similar way.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware you can not change this via css however when you bring up your browsers print dialog it should present you with an option to exclude headers and footers (i.e. page number and url).

Answer (score 0):

Is not possible to remove the browser's default strings. You can achieve in Internet Explorer exploiting the "features" (also knows as bugs) that they provide you, but in the rest of browsers you can't.